# Regex to remove certain repeating characters but ignore others

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex function to detect if a character is repeated 3 or more times.

I am using

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(.)\1{2}");
```

This works fine, however I need to amend the regex so that it ignores the '.' character. 
I am unsure what to put in so that the full-stop character is not included in the regex match

So

"some string aaa"
"some string with bbbb content" 
"some zzz string"  would match

but

"some string a..."
"some string with a content...." would be ok

Can anyone advise? Thanks

Comment: Replace `.` with  `[^.]`

Comment: because there was nothing repeating. ex. `a...`